# How can i use datepicker format look like yyMMdd

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, datepicker

i'm using this datepicker below(edited) since its work alrd

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        buttontanggalawal = findViewById (R.id.button_tanggal_awal);
        buttontanggalakhir = findViewById (R.id.button_tanggal_akhir);
        textView = findViewById (R.id.textView);

        buttontanggalawal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
            }
        });

        buttontanggalakhir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        String tanggalawalpublic = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(c.getTime());

        buttontanggalawal.setText(currentDateString);
    }
```

and this is my design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Search">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:text="date"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="open date picker" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my datepicker code

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
    }
}
```

and if i choose on the date in datepicker i got an result as 25/11/21

how can change the format and turn the datepicker result into 211125 ???
the yyMMdd thing

and i need two time picker on 1 same activity and gonna need them for searching using startAt()

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ?

Comment: well i saw some of tutorial on some place and search in the other website, but i don't know how to implement that  @AdriaanKoster

Answer (score 0):

Where you do:

```
String currentDateString = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());
```

you need to use a different part of the [SimpleDateFormat API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
String currentDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: and how about if i have 2 datepicker on 1 activity?, i edit the question, try to check on top code, the .java file. i having 2 button for 2 datepicker, but i only can show 1

Comment: @billy this is a different question. The actual answer should be evaluated according to the original post

Comment: @fantaghirocco ah im sorry letme change it back